# Do system call tables in Linux change over time?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

Specifically, for x86 64-bit architecture, will the syscall table ever change? For instance, could there be additions of new syscalls or relocations of certain syscalls? I am fairly new to the concept and was wondering about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New syscalls will be added, but existing ones won't be renumbered or removed, as doing so would break userspace programs, which Linus is famously dead-set against ever doing.